# extending automorphisms in complete boolean algebras

Tags: logic, set-theory, boolean-algebra, forcing

Suppose $A$ is a complete subalgebra of a complete boolean algebra $B$.  Suppose $f : A \to A$ is an automorphism.  Then $f$ can be extended to an automorphism of $B$.  I can see this using the fact that $B$ is equivalent to a two-step forcing iteration $A * \check B/\dot G$ and using automorphism-of-names.  But I am curious, is there a simple and direct way to define this extension of $f$ without reference to forcing?

**Edit:**  Comments show that the premise of my question was wrong. But I learned something so I will leave it to the moderators whether this question needs deleting.

Comment: This won't be true for all CBA's.  Here's the example I'm thinking of.  Let $B = P(\mathbb{N})$.  Let $a_n$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) be a partition of $\mathbb{N}$ with $|a_n| = n$, and let $A$ be the set of all possible unions of the $a_n$'s.  Then each $a_n$ is an atom in $A$, and you can define an automorphism of $A$ by permuting the $a_n$'s however you like.  But every automorphism of $B$ is induced by a permutation, and hence can't map any $a_n$ to $a_m$ for any $n\neq m$.

Comment: @Paul What do you mean by "every automorphism of $\mathbb B$ is induced by a permutation"?

Comment: @PaulMcKenney, thanks for the counterexample.  I was assuming the name $\dot{B/G}$ was invariant under the name-automorphism induced by $f$, which is not always true.

Comment: @Stefan: Well, every automorphism $f$ of $B$ must permute the atoms, which are just the singletons.  So we get a permutation $\pi$ of $\mathbb{N}$.  It's then easy to see that $f(A)$ is equal to the image of $A$ under $\pi$, for any set $A$.

Comment: @Paul Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Here is a simpler counterexample than the one suggested by @Paul. Consider the two-step iteration $A$ chooses one of two atoms, and $\dot B$ is defined as adding one Cohen real, or $(2^{\aleph_0})^+$ Cohen reals, depending on the atom chosen. Then $A$ has two automorphisms, but only the identity preserves $\dot B$. This is despite $A$ being weakly homogeneous, and $\Vdash_A\dot B\text{ is weakly homogeneous}$. In short, the iteration of two homogeneous forcings need not be homogeneous.

Comment: @Paul: Maybe you can upgrade your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As was brought up in the comments, there is actually a counterexample.  I'll give a simpler one than I gave in the comments, with the same idea.  Take $B = P(\{1,2,3\})$, and $$A = \{\emptyset,\{1\},\{2,3\},\{1,2,3\}\}.$$  Then $A$ has the automorphism which switches $\{1\}$ and $\{2,3\}$.  But this can't extend to an automorphism of $B$, since every automorphism of $B$ must send $\{1\}$ to either $\{2\}$ or $\{3\}$.